# Why there is an error when it case using vlookup for int type

Tags: vba, excel

I need to use vlookup module in VBA of EXCEL
So I Use the "Application.vlookup"

But There is an error when it case using vlookup for **int type**

If Use 'vlookup' as a basic function in EXCEL,
There is no error.

But It happend when I use "Application.vlookup" in VBA of EXCEL

Please note capture.

[image]

I really want to know how it can be solved

Comment: Your lookup range is C6:D12 - do you see a problem there?  That's not where your table is.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tim Williams has mentioned in the comment, the problem is that your range is `C6:D12` and your data is on `C4:D10`.

In VBA, instad of writing:

```
Range(Range("C" & 6), Range("D" & 12))
```

you may simply write `Range("C6:D12")`, it is 100% the same and is really understandable.

[MSDN - refer to Cells and Ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221536(v=office.11).aspx)